# Search and display all Exceptions in VisualStudio2010 solution in a grouped view/list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am trying to find every exception used in within a big solution. I am doing this so I can replace generic Exceptions of Type "Exception" or "ArgumentException" with more specific ones.

What I tried at first was using the build in "Show Using"-Feature which, in case the Object is beeing used more than once" shows a nice tree-view of all the findings. It's great to navigate.

Only Problem ist that I don't know every Type that was used. If I use the normal search feature I get a simple List.

Using ReSharper I found that I can use the "Find" > "Search with PAttern" Feature. Only Problem here is that it is automatically case sensitive and "whole words" only.

Is there a build in feature like the "Usages"-Feature for a search?

PS: I also tried the "Find in File", that is just a list. I get every occurance of the word exception, which is helpfull but I lose the ability to navigate through a tree view.

Comment: How did you try using search with pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [argument placeholders](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Search_with_Pattern.html) to search for anything that inherits from `System.Exception`

[image: Create Type Placeholder dialog with "Or dervied type" check box checked]

And I'm not sure what you mean about it being case-sensitive. I tried the below (notice that I'm in VB and I've failed to capitalize Throw`and`New`), but it still matched all the places I throw exceptions in my code.

[image: Incorrect casing pattern example]

I wasn't however able to search for just `$type$`, but this should catch any exceptions you throw in your code. You could try similar patterns to look for methods that handle exceptions. I'm using ReSharper 7.1.